# Getting the pathfile name in the fileupload using if else

Tags: c#, asp.net

The bold text is the one I've been wanting to probably solve I'm not really good at English and even explaining the process or codes so sorry if my question is quite not understandable.

```
  private void Update_Employee()
    {
        string filename = FileUpload2.FileName.ToString();
        string fileName = Path.GetFileName(filename);
        **if (txtImage.Text == "filename")
        {
            FileUpload2 = filename;
        }**
        else
        {
            FileUpload2.PostedFile.SaveAs(Server.MapPath(FileImage) + fileName);
        }
        txtImage.Text = filename.ToString();
```

Comment: You might get more help if you took off the vb.net tag and added a C# tag.

Comment: What is `if (txtImage.Text == "filename")` trying to achieve? Did you mean `if (txtImage.Text == filename)`?

Comment: Yes. so whenever the txtImage has  the filename I'm expecting that in the fileupload the pathfile of the txtImage would be there. I'm not really sure though, sorry if it's confusing. It's kind of hard for me to explain it, really.

Comment: You cannot set the file programmatically on a FileUpload control. Can't be done. The file must be selected by the user. There are a lot of posts about this here and on the web.